# How to set different conditions for each row in table using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have a table:-

```
<table style="width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Row1</th>
                <th>Row2</th>
                <th>Row3</th>
                <th>Row4</th>
                <th>Row5</th>
                <th>Row6</th>
                <th>Row7</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in ListDisplay">
                <td>{{row.val1}}-{{row.val2}}</td>
                <td>{{row.val3 != null ? row.val3 : "&nbsp;"}}</td>
                <td><div class="width">{{row.val4 != null ? row.val4 : "&nbsp;"}}</div>
                </td>
                <td>{{row.val5 != null ? row.val5 : "&nbsp;"}}</td>
                <td>{{row.val6 != null ? (row.val3 == "1"? row.val6 : (row.val6 | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy')) : "&nbsp;"}}</td>
                <td>{{row.val7}} {{row.val8 != null ? row.val8 : "&nbsp;"}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

With each `<td></td>` tag consists of different conditions. I want to do ng-repeat on `<td></td>` tag. But due to above conditions that is not possible.Is there a  workaround for this?

Comment: You can try to write this: `<td ng-repeat="item in [row.val1+'-'+row.val2, ...]"></td>` or prepare data in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a kind of bad way and have no idea why don't you use 'ng-if',

but I suggest one way

Check this fiddle.

[table with ng-repeat](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/ztdhyex8/5/)

```
$scope.setTdValue = function( row, idx ){
    var result = null;
    switch(idx){
        case 0 : 
            result = row.val1 - row.val2 
            break;
        case 1 :
            ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ngif on each td tag. More information about ngif can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

Comment: But I want to use ng-repeat only. Then the above solution won't work

Comment: What is wrong with using ngif in each td and display your value based on the condition?